# Can i use C libraries (Headers) in RenderScript With include

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

I want to use for example a library written for a specific mathematic calculation in C with renderscript. I want to know is it possible to add them like include <'math.h'> . to be more specefic the library is about ordinary differential equations (well known in matlab with ode23).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot include C code in your renderscript files.

Comment: Why? so what can i do if it is an important library?

Comment: Renderscript is not C or C++. It is ultimately compiled into something platform specific. It could be assembly for the application processor, an onboard DSP or the GPU. You either need to rewrite the code for RS or just use JNI to call the C code from Java.

Comment: So you mean i have to use NDK?

Comment: or is it possible to use JNI with renderscript too?

Comment: You can call renderscript from NDK code, but not the other way around.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer Hi do you have an example of calling rs from NDK code? THX

Comment: Have a look at the samples in the ndk, I believe the is a rs example.